# How to force a re-render on a uibModal dialog in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using the uibModal framework in AngularJS as below:

```
vm.openTotalScore = () => {
    $uibModal.open({
         templateUrl: 'app/modules/scoreforms/cost/scoreform.html',
         scope: $scope,
         controller: 'CostScoreFormController',
         controllerAs: 'vm',
         backdrop: 'static',
         resolve: {
             rankingSettings: function() {
                 return vm.rankingdata;
             },
             score: function() {
                 return vm.risk.TotalScore;
             },
             costScoringData: function(ScoreFormService){            
                 var fields = vm.risktitle.split(' ');

                 return ScoreFormService.getCostScoringData(vm.state.params.riskId, vm.impacttypename, fields[0]);
             },
             currencysymbol: function() {
                 return vm.currencysymbol;
             }
         }
     }).opened.then(function(success){

     });
}
```

and when the modal form is opened, I need to be able to trigger a re-rendering of the graphical elements on the modal form.  I am using the DevExpress DevExtreme controls and one of their controls does not draw properly until I refresh/resize the page.  They have informed me that I need to render on their control once the form is visible.  However, I am unsure how to do this from the controller which opened the form.

The only way I can think of doing this is to, somehow, tell the controller that the form is now opened and the form can be re-rendered.

The alternative would be for the controller to know automatically that the form is now visible but I am not sure how to do this.

I am passing the uibModalInstance into the controller as below so can I handle the opened promise there?

```
constructor($state, $scope, $translate, $stateParams, $filter, $uibModalInstance, logger, rankingSettings, score, costScoringData, currencysymbol) { //, score) 
{
    'ngInject';
    var vm = this;
    vm.logger = logger;
    vm.state = $state;
    vm.translate = $translate;
    vm.logger = logger;
    vm.submitted = false;
    vm.modelInstance = $uibModalInstance;

    vm.costScoringData = costScoringData;
    vm.rankingSettings = rankingSettings;   
    vm.score = score;
    vm.currencysymbol = currencysymbol;

    vm.cancel = function () {
        vm.modelInstance.close();  
    };

    this.getOptions();

    this.loadGridData();
    this.showDevExtremeGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The alternative would be for the controller to know automatically that the form is now visible but I am not sure how to do this.

Try wrapping your code in the controller that you want to know "automatically that the form is now visible" with $`timeout`

```
$timeout(function(){
    //Your codes goes here
});
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)